# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable is missing

Tags: kentico

I upgraded my site from Kentico 10.0 to 11.0. When I load site then I am getting the following error

> Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable, Version=16.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I installed an SDK package and also tried `Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM -Version 16.1.7414.1200` but not getting 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable' dll.

Could you please suggest a solution for me?

Comment: Open the NuGet package manager in VS and make sure all projects reference the same version of the `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` package, which should be 16.1.6621.1200 according to the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-11#UpgradingtoKentico11-Upgradeoverview)

Comment: Thanks, I installed specific dll then error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Open the NuGet package manager in VS and make sure all projects reference the same version of the `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` package, which should be 16.1.6621.1200 according to the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-11#UpgradingtoKentico11-Upgradeoverview).